# Is it possible to turn a list of whole numbers in to a sine graph?

Tags: trigonometry

The title of this question is super misleading. I apologize for that. I'm not a mathematician and I have no idea how to word what I'm asking for ... but I'm going to give it a shot.

If I have a list of numbers, let's say:

`[0, 3, 3, 7, 8, 10, 10, 13, 13, 15, 18, 20, 22, 23, 24, 26, 26, 28, 29, 30]`

What I would like those numbers to represent is a graph like this:

[image]

Ultimately, what I'm trying to represent here is,

0 = I am not sure what I'm doing
1-14 = I'm progressing slowly
15 = I've figured it out and it's all down hill from here
16-29 = I've figured out the hard part and I'm working on it
30 = I'm all done now

Comment: More context would probably be helpful.  For what purpose are you trying to display these numbers in that form?

Comment: The goal is that I'd like to keep track of my progress on a specific task. Typically when I start something, I have no idea what I'm doing ... as I progress and learn, I'm ultimately gaining knowledge as well as finishing that task (numbers 0-14). When I get to a point that I know what I'm doing (15) I still have some work to do, but it's all downhill from here (16-30). I apologize, I wish I knew how to explain this better. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for. (If not, just tell me)

If you want an equation, $f(x)=\sin(\pi\frac{x}{30})$ would probably be best. If you want to restrict the domain from 0 to 30, you can add the restriction $\{ x| x\in [0, 30]\}$

$f(0)=0$

$f(15)=1$

$f(30) = 0$

Make sure to graph this in radians.
This is what your graph would look like (after scaling the axes accordingly)

[image]

Comment: Holy cow that worked! It's completely irrelevant to the answer, but would you mind linking me to or elaborating on what you mean by "make sure to graph this in radians"? I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @BryanRay Well in the mathematics community, we typically use radians to measure angles rather than degrees. For example, we would represent $360$ degrees by $2\pi$ radians (the circumference of a unit circle is $2\pi (1)$, it takes 360 degrees to go around a circle). If you use a graphing calculator, make sure it says RAD at the top rather than DEG (desmos is automatically set to radians).

Comment: @BryanRay Also, to convert from radians to degrees use the formula: degrees $=$ radians $* \frac{180}{\pi}$. For degrees to radians, use: radians $=$ degrees $* \frac{\pi}{180}$

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking for, this might be an approach:

$y = sin(\pi \frac{myInput}{30})$

where myInput is the number from 0-30.  The sine function I am assuming is one that uses "radians" as the angle measure.

I hope this helps.